# My ant build suddenly started giving javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property

Tags: java, ant, build, jndi, hibernate-tools

I have a build.xml file which was working perfectly till yesterday, today it suddenly stared giving  below exception... I did not do any modifications in the application, it was successfully identifying JNDI name previously, I cannot understand what has caused it to fail now.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
```

build log as below.

```
schemaexport:
[hibernatetool] Executing Hibernate Tool with a JPA Configuration
[hibernatetool] 1. task: hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
[hibernatetool] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
[hibernatetool] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[hibernatetool] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[hibernatetool] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
[hibernatetool] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/vseelsh_workspace/vseelsh_perforce_ws/pem_rd/NBDX/nbdx/lib/gwt/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-2.3.0/samples/DynaTableRf/war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[hibernatetool] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/slf4j/impl/main/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.0.0.GA.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
[hibernatetool] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
[hibernatetool] An exception occurred while running exporter #2:hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
[hibernatetool] To get the full stack trace run ant with -verbose
[hibernatetool] org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:/nbdxDS]
[hibernatetool] javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

BUILD FAILED
C:\vseelsh_workspace\vseelsh_perforce_ws\pem_rd\NBDX\nbdx\build.xml:189: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:/nbdxDS]
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.reportException(HibernateToolTask.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [java:/nbdxDS]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.Hbm2DDLExporter.doStart(Hbm2DDLExporter.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask.execute(ExporterTask.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:186)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getNameParser(InitialContext.java:499)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.parseName(JndiServiceImpl.java:86)
    ... 25 more

Total time: 13 seconds
```

Comment: does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your hibernate version is upgraded,so "Error parsing JNDI name" may occur.

If your hibernate-cfg.xml file is auto-generated, then you should remove name attribute in the session factory to avoid JNDI parsing issue.

```
 <session-factory>
```

instead of

```
 <session-factory name="">
```